# SQL change Result by case

Tags: mysql, sql-server, sqlite, sql

so I have this code it works fine

```
SELECT NAME, 
       Country, 
       NORMAL_STATE, 
       CURRENT_STATE
FROM SOMS_TABLE
WHERE SOMS_TABLE.NAME LIKE 'AR%' AND 
      NORMAL_STATE <> CURRENT_STATE
ORDER BY SOMS_TABLE.Country ASC
```

output is 
[image]

 
but instead I want change 1's and 0's to OPEN & CLOSED 
[image]

Thanks

Comment: MySQL, SQL Server, sqlite, can you pick an RDBMS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select name,
    Country,
    case NORMAL_STATE
        when 1 then 'OPEN'
        when 0 then 'CLOSED'
        else 'UNKNOWN'
    end as NORMAL_STATE,
    case CURRENT_STATE
        when 1 then 'OPEN'
        when 0 then 'CLOSED'
        else 'UNKNOWN'
    end as CURRENT_STATE
from SOMS_TABLE
where name like 'AR%'
    and NORMAL_STATE <> CURRENT_STATE
order by Country
```

Comment: Thanks nice and simple with more options

Answer (score 1):

Use this

```
CASE NORMAL_STATE
    WHEN 1 THEN 'OPEN'
    WHEN 2 THEN 'CLOSED'
END AS NORMAL_STATE
```

And similarly for `CURRENT_STATE`

Answer (score 0):

you could use an IF statement

```
SELECT NAME, Country, 
       IF(NORMAL_STATE > 0,'OPEN','CLOSED'), 
       IF(CURRENT_STATE > 0,'OPEN','CLOSED') 
FROM SOMS_TABLE 
WHERE SOMS_TABLE.NAME LIKE 'AR%' AND 
      NORMAL_STATE <> CURRENT_STATE 
ORDER BY SOMS_TABLE.Country ASC
```